# Is it possible to display "visual client keys" in the sshd log?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, sshd

I found recently that the ssh `VisualHostKey` setting is very useful for server "users" to determine that their host is the correct host, but is there a way to log the "visual key" (as logged by `ssh-keygen`) into the sshd logs, as a server maintainer?

In some cases, it might not be needed, but if I'm the only person that should be remoting in, it would be useful for me to, at a glance, determine which of the (multiple) valid ssh keys are in use, and to (again, at a glance) notice if there's a key I haven't seen before remoting in.

---

This is *not* talking about the ability for a user to see the host's key, rather it's about the server logging the visual key of each user.